# Mobile header and footer disappear

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, mobile, app, salesforce-mobile-app

I have a button that opens a aura component (with a LWC inside) in a modal. When I use the standard app from Salesofrce and click on the button, the component shows but the standard header and footer disappeared. How can I do to maintain both?
*The two red squares shows the two elements that disappear[image]